# Cordova sqlite-storage plugin transaction (executeSql) doesn't run sometimes

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I'm a very new member of this site and this will my first question. So There is my sample Code:

```
myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM places', [], function (tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
        alert(len);
    }, null);
    })
```

So my problem is the following: On my mobilephone I get the result (A310) and it works fine, but on my tablet and Android emulator I cannot get the alert and the value of course. I'm using the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin. The code is placed in the device ready function.

Do you have any idea, how can I fix this?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting an error callback instead of null and see what the error is:

```
}, function (e) {console.log(" FAILED: " + e.message);})
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I found the solution. I used the error callback and then I got an error message (Table not found...), so after that I realized I must use another plugin too (Sqlite db-copy), inorder to copy the database file from the www folder... By the way the error log was the starter point. Thanks